# Update Custom UItableView cell text from uipickerview

Tags: uitableview

I have a Custom table View Cell that have a right label and a left label
I want to change the right label text after selecting objects from ui pickerview

```
-(void) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component  {
if(pickerView ==myPicker){
    if(component==0){
        CustomeCell * cell =(CustomeCell*) [detailTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
        cell.rightLabel.text=@"Hi";
        NSLog(@"Section 0 %@",[allFoodType objectAtIndex:row]);
         [detailTableView reloadData];
    }
```

however nothing  change after I have selected the objects from picker view

I have no idea about that , Can anyone give me a solution how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the ViewController that has both cell and UIpickerView as the delegate and datasource for both UItableViewCell and UIPickerView? Also is the cell within a UItableView?